# Python ODBC Driver Manager SQLDriverConnect error

Tags: python, windows, odbc

The database teacher in college gave me a task to get all the fields from the "Кураторы" table. Yep, he likes MS Acces...
Seems like something's wrong with my drivers. I'm using Windows 10 N tho. Already have checked ODBC data sources and founded some curious things. There are [Microsoft Access Driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YvGY.png), but on ODBC Data Source Administrator ([x32](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2LUY.png)) only! [x64](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRtnV.png) one has [only one SQL Server driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cRXo.png)

Using pyodbc-4.0.30-cp38-cp38-win_amd64 version of pyodbc and x64 Python 3.8

Getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Documents/College/4th grade/DB/13.09.py", line 3, in <module>
    conn = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver(*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\Users\reddk\Desktop\db.accdb')
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Here's the code:

```
import pyobc
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver(*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\Users\reddk\Desktop\db.accdb') # connecting to DB
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Кураторы') # request
result = cursor.fetchall() # converting the result of a query to the list of rows and assign it to the result
for row in result:
    print(row)      # printing each row of the list
```

Appreciate any help sm!

Comment: So you already know that you can't use ODBC Access driver in x64 Python. Why not try a 32-bit Python?

Comment: Good note, I'll try it